# How do I check for not just reserved keywords, but also any built-in function or "special variable"?

Tags: php, built-in

I'm finally able to check for any "reserved keyword" in PHP, such as "if", "for" and "else". I found a useful hack on Stack Exchange that does it by essentially baking it into a temporary PHP code string and then checking it with token_get_all().

However, I still have no idea how I would check whether a given string corresponds to a built-in ***function***, such as "mb_strpos" or "dl". I also have not found a way to check whether a given variable name corresponds to a "special, built-in ***variable***", such as "argc", "argv", "_GET", "_POST", "php_errormsg", etc.

I'm trying to avoid making a manual list of these in my code at all costs. I really dislike the idea of having such things "hardcoded" and feeling the constant stress of having to keep it up to date as PHP evolves and new versions add stuff to this list.

I wish PHP had a single, unified function such as:

```
var_dump(is_php_stuff('mb_strpos'));
var_dump(is_php_stuff('$_GET'));
var_dump(is_php_stuff('_GET'));
var_dump(is_php_stuff('argc'));
var_dump(is_php_stuff('if'));
var_dump(is_php_stuff('myownstuff'));
```

And output:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
```

That sure would be mighty swell, but by this point, I'm pretty sure no such thing exists.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why do you even need such a thing? What did you intend to do when you created a checker for reserved keywords and on what data did you make it? Far more details are needed to even understand what is the problem and why it appeared

Comment: You may be better off looking at a parser - https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/component/Walking_the_AST.markdown is probably a good start.

Comment: Regardless of your intentions, it always comes off as condescending when people try to "second-guess" what I "really" meant to ask, or insinuate that what I'm doing is somehow wrong just because it's not immediately obvious what I'm using it for. Those libraries are nearly always a million times more work to try to deal with than just doing it on my own. The answer is that I'm doing "parsing of PHP code, because the existing solutions are all broken in one way or another". Having invested a ton of time and energy in this, I'm not about to go back to dealing with the libraries that others made.

Comment: It might seem that way to you, but it's perfectly natural to second-guess and ask for clarification of the big picture. The quality of the questions posted here really do warrant that. We cannot know what your background is, how experienced you are and what you've tried so far if you haven't told us. All that being said - have you tried forking and improving an existing parser rather than developing your own from scratch?

Comment: If you're writing a parser on your own you'll have to hard code the tokens anyway. However any dynamic way that would come to my mind would be to check for function with `function_extists()` or `is_callable()` and `isset` for variables.